# How to stop bootstrap affix from scrolling?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, affix

I'm trying to use the bootstrap affix plugin, and cannot figure out how to make it strop scrolling, here  is an example of what I'm trying to do. http://www.bootply.com/F6daY1KXoJ

I tried to use the technique described here: http://codepen.io/henrylfan/pen/HBnrJ however it doesn't work when referencing a 'bottom' that isn't in the same parent as the affixed item.

```
//select a referenced box for bottom alignment
var bottomReferenceBox = $('.reference-box');

//calculate the bottom position
var bottomOffLine = $(document).height() - bottomReferenceBox.offset().top -       bottomReferenceBox.outerHeight();

$('.affix').affix({
  offset: {
    top: 100,
    bottom: bottomOffLine
  }
})
```

Comment: I actually found a solution to this plus other problems which came up, will post that soon.  Thanks all!

Comment: Please do not use "bootstrap" tag, use "twitter-bootstrap" since it means something else